# How to calculate number of swaps in permutations?

Tags: java, permutation

I have this code below, I would like to know how to calculate the number of swaps. I used a count variable to figure it out, but I was getting different number than the computer. I figure the number of swaps would be 2 * (n - 1)(n - 2)...(n - n + 1). For n == 4, the computer got 128, and I got 48. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void permute(int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            printOutPut();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
          swap(i, n);
          permute1(n-1);
          swap(i, n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just `2*n`? Is this a recurtion? You seem to have a spelliung error `permute1`?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri ironic to misspell *spelling error*

Comment: @bureaquete, my error doesn't break any recursion :) Just typing from mobile.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I had multiple permutation methods so I named it permute1(). Thanks for looking out though!

Answer (score 1):

The code  defines a recursion:

```
num_swaps(0) = 0
num_swaps(i) = i * (num_swaps(i - 1) + 2)
```

or with more math-like symbols:

```
s_{n+1} = (n + 1) (s_n + 2)
s_0 = 0
s_1 = 2
s_2 = 8
s_3 = 30
s_4 = 128
```

You can probably solve that recursion for a general `n` using techniques from maths, but this verifies that the computer is right

**Edit**: I was trying to find a solution for general `n`, ended up on wolfram alpha and the solution presented had incomplete gamma functions and stuff. So, don't expect the calculation to be easy!